# How do you describe feeling suffocated?

Tags: word-choice

I'm trying to explain how you react when someone cuddles you and it freaks you out to the point of feeling suffocated, like panicky?

Comment: ***smothering***

Comment: How you react is a reflex to the sensation.

Comment: The hug is so tight that it takes your breath away.

Comment: Thankyou...I don't know if there's a button of sorts to like your individual comments..newbie here, but thankyou.